# How does time dilation affect the ability of photons to escape a black hole?

Tags: time-dilation

The curved space explanation of why light can't escape from a black hole is great but... I'm also wondering how time-dilation affects a subatomic particle trying to escape at the speed of light. 
Can one even see a photon if it's going slower than the speed of light, what would it look like?
This also begs the question does time stop at the center of black hole. This would certainly keep a photon from escaping.

Comment: OOOh ok I am new, I asked too many questions at a time. (Don't laugh. How do I get rid of the sparkly mouse trails?)

Comment: First Assumption - I believe I'm not a local observer as the local black hole is about 3,000 light years away.

Comment: A photon seeming to be moving slower-than-light from a distance is a seperate idea that was a curiousity to revisit and does not likely weigh on the original question.

Comment: LOL no luck on the sparkles

Comment: Wow I didn't realize how significant an event horizon was as far as a border between escape and non escape I thought of it more as a sliding scale with some interesting borders.

Comment: You said that if the particle starts inside the event horizon, then it cannot escape no matter what it tries to do. Is that the curved space explanation? (I hope so, it took me 4 months to understand "The God Particle" by Leon Lederman and Dick Teresi. I refused to gloss over anything (I caved on the details except the collider details)

Comment: It did inspire a joke... If a photon falls in the aether and there's no one there to observe it... does it still make a wave?

Comment: COOL! The convergence of time-dilation and curved space creates (for me an interesting border). Perhaps not for the mathematicians but...

Comment: So just to summarize. There is no escape velocity (ad hoc) beyond the event horizon. Even in the theoretical due to the origin of the particles that created the hole. Gall darn.... I'z ain't smartser than that hawky guy (Requiescat in Pace)